# Invalid Parameter: Topic Name Error when publishing to AWS SNS arn endpoint

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

In Java, I am trying to publish a AWS SNS message to a specific ARN endpoint using the following code:

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNS;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.PublishRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.PublishResult;

...

AmazonSNS snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(System.getenv("AWS_KEY"), System.getenv("AWS_SECRET")));

snsClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));

String message = "{\"APNS_SANDBOX\":\"{\\\"aps\\\":{\\\"type\\\":\\\"XXX\\\",\\\"email\\\":\\\"XXX@gmail.com\\\",\\\"alert\\\":\\\"some alert\\\"}}\"}";

PublishResult pr = snsClient.publish(new PublishRequest("arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:XXX:endpoint/APNS_SANDBOX/XXX/XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX", message));
```

I am consistently getting the following error message:

`Invalid parameter: Topic Name (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: XXX`

Any idea on this?

I can publish to the ARN endpoint with no issues from the SNS console and I have tried different variations of the message

Answer (score 11):

You should use `TargetArn` instead of `TopicArn` which is the first parameter of `PublishRequest` constructor.

```
PublishRequest pr = new PublishRequest();
pr.TargetArn = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:XXX:endpoint/APNS_SANDBOX/XXX/XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX";
pr.Message = message;
```

(maybe it is too late to answer lol)

Answer (score 8):

The error message is a bit confusing. If you provide the wrong topic ARN, you get error message saying `Invalid Parameter: Topic Name` as well.

From what you posted, it looks like you might have used the subscription ARN, instead of topic ARN. Topic ARN format looks like this `arn:aws:sns:AWS_REGION:AWS_ACCOUNT_NUMBER:TOPIC_NAME`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem was this:
String message = "{"APNS_SANDBOX":"{\"aps\":{\"type\":\"XXX\",\"email\":\"XXX@gmail.com\",\"alert\":\"some alert\"}}"}";

instead it should have been:
String message = "{"APNS_SANDBOX":"{\"aps\":{\"type\":\"XXX\",\"email\":\"XXX@gmail.com\",\"alert\":\"somealert\"}}"}";

You cant put name of the topic with spaces. So "some alert" will be rejected. "somealert" will be accepted.

In case someone else stumbles upon this problem.

Comment: Ok. I`ll keep that in mind in the future. Thanks for the tip.